# project doesn't build correctly? or is it me?

Tags: java

I use Netbeans IDE, some where in the code I included this

`ImageIcon accept_icon = new ImageIcon("src/images/accept.png");`

When I run the project inside the IDE it display fine. However, when I try to build the project, it seems like external sources that I specified (images, template files, etc...) does not get included. Is it because how I specified the source (e.g `src/images/accept.png` ) ? If it is, how should I solve this problem? Sorry to ask such a simple question, Im quite new to java.

Comment: for example: ImageIcon("C:/images/accept.png");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about building a jar and then running it then you have to embed the resources inside the jar explicitly if you want them there, and use the `getResourceAsStream()` method to use them.

See [here](http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Load your resource from the **classpath** instead of the file system.

This way you won't be dependent on the current directory, absolute paths, ...

Comment: new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/accept.png")));

Answer (score 1):

Consider following the example on the tutorial page and load it *relative to your class* as follows:

The following two excerpts are from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html:

```
/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                    String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

> In the preceding snippet, the first
>   argument to the ImageIcon constructor
>   is **relative to the location of the
>   current class**, and will be resolved to
>   an absolute URL. The description
>   argument is a string that allows
>   assistive technologies to help a
>   visually impaired user understand what
>   information the icon conveys.

---

Is your class in the default package? Try putting the image in a subfolder directly below your current class and use

```
ImageIcon accept_icon = new ImageIcon("images/accept.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to unpack the jar and see if the image exists. If it doesnt, look for proper steps of packaging the application

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using a relative path to your image file. Trying making it a full (absolute) path (e.g. "/root/src/images/accept.png") and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi, would that make the program less portable? it always has to look to the absolute path?